# I upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and my trackpad is not working properly

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, dell

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 and my trackpad is not working properly now. I think this has something to do with the adaptive acceleration of touchpad or something(the speed is automatically varying now.For example if i intent to quickly go to close button it it wont be where i want it to be, it will sometime slowdown or speed up.it seems **Other buttons** in the screen is also having an effect on this issue).
I am using **DELL inspiron 15 3567** laptop. The trackpad was with earlier versions of ubuntu. I tried to get drivers for ubuntu from dell [website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/indhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3567-laptop/drivers). But they have got no drivers for ubuntu. 
I thought i will get used to this so i waited for over a month now. But i am seriously facing an issue.

I tried reducing the speed of the trackpad also. Even that didn't help.

Please help me solve this problem.

Output of dmesg lspsi and lsusb 
[link](https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1uwf)

Comment: "Please provide a solution for this problem so that i can revert back to the older trackpad." - askubuntu is not an official support channel, we are all users and professionals that provide help during our spare time. BUT, we are glad to help you with solving your problem yourself.

Please add some information on this matter: output of `dmesg`, `lscpi` and `lsusb` should be the bare minimum.

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann Sorry if i sounded offensive in any way.. I will edit that part and post the details..

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann i edited the question with the info. Please help me with this

Comment: dmesg states that "psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN0609 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org." - give it a try and see if this helps?

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann sorry for my ignorance but i dont know how to set psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things which did not work. At last i updated my ubuntu to 18.04 Bionic Beaver. This fixed my issue. I know this is not a real solution to the problem, but as of now i have not got any other solution.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that info with us and sorry no one could find a better solution to your problem!  :)  *Answer upvoted!*